# GetEnumerator movenext System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ienumerable, nullreferenceexception

I get an exception on the `MoveNext` method

```
    var e = t.GetEnumerator();
    if (!e.MoveNext()) return;
    do
    {
        Data.Add((BaseModel)e.Current); 
    } while (e.MoveNext());
```

`e.current` has a value but then the exception occurred in `e.MoveNext()`

also casting throws an exception

```
var bb = t.Cast<BaseModel>().ToList();
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Edit

The full code creates an expression tree from a generic.

```
list.Where(x => (x.property.toString().ToLower() ?? "").contains(parameter.toString().ToLower()));

var t = GetFilteredList(list, SelectedProperty, parameter);

private IEnumerable GetFilteredList(IEnumerable target, PropertyInfo info, object searchValues)
{


    //Get target's T 
    var targetType = target.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    if (targetType == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Should be IEnumerable<T>", "target");

    #region LeftSide

    //Create a p parameter with the type T of the items in the -> target IEnumerable<T> t =>
    var containsLambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "t");

    //Create a property accessor using the property name -> p.#propertyName#
    var property = Expression.Property(containsLambdaParameter, targetType, info.Name);

    // property Constant
    var propertyConstant = Expression.Constant(info.PropertyType);

    // property to string
    var propertyToString = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);

    var propertyToLower = Expression.Call(propertyToString, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);


    // p.#propertyName# == null ? null : string.Empty; get default value if property value is null
    BinaryExpression nullCheck = Expression.Coalesce(propertyToLower, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));



    #endregion

    #region RightSide

    var searchValuesAsConstant = Expression.Constant(searchValues, searchValues.GetType());

    var searchValuesToString = Expression.Call(searchValuesAsConstant, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);

     var  searchValuesToLower = Expression.Call(searchValuesToString, "ToLower", null);

    #endregion
    ////Get searchValues's T for Enumerable searchValues
    //var searchValuesType = searchValues.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    //if (searchValuesType == null)
    //    throw new ArgumentException("Should be IEnumerable<T>", "searchValues");

    var  containsBody = Expression.Call(nullCheck, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, searchValuesToLower);


    //// for Enumerable searchValues
    //var containsBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { searchValuesType }, searchValuesAsConstant, property);

    //Create a lambda expression with the parameter p -> p => searchValues.Contains(p.Id)
    var containsLambda = Expression.Lambda(containsBody, containsLambdaParameter);

    //Create a constant with the -> IEnumerable<T> target
    var targetAsConstant = Expression.Constant(target, target.GetType());

    var whereBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Where", new[] { targetType }, targetAsConstant, containsLambda);


    //target.Where(p => searchValues.Contains(p.Id))
    var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable>>(whereBody).Compile();

    return whereLambda.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: And what is `t` here? Where did it come from? Enumerators are numerous and plenty, and most likely the error is in your code - perhaps an iterator block, perhaps a LINW "where" clause, etc. The stack trace would help, as would running it through a debugger.

Comment: I added the behind code to get t value

Comment: I think it happend if list has null values even if i added if null set as empty string

Comment: I see the update - that's getting much better, but we still can't *run* that; if I were to speculate: I'd be asking things like "is `.property` returning `null`?" and "is `parameter` actually `null`?"

Comment: .property may return null so the code tries to make a very strange behaviour (null.ToString().ToLower()) that is the problem I found

Comment: In particular, note that your `list.Where(...)` which shows what you are *doing* with the expression tree version - *isn't actually evaluating the loop* - you'd need to add a `.Count()` or `.ToList()` or something on the end to force the loop to actually run; my guess is that this will show the same error. So ultimately, presumably the problem is: your predicate doesn't properly consider null values?